# MySQL high performance difference 2 similar databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently upgrading from TecDoc 2015 Quarter 2 database to TecDoc 2015 Quarter 4 database.

Q2 Database:
240,838,107 rows    InnoDB  utf8_general_ci 23.2 GiB

Q4 Database:
265,508,380 rows    InnoDB  utf8_general_ci 23.8 GiB

Indexes and table structures are identical.

The main difference lies in running query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ART_ID AS AID, ART_ARTICLE_NR AS ARTICLE, SUP_BRAND AS BRAND,
        SUP_ID AS BID, DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT AS TD_NAME 
FROM LINK_GA_STR 
    INNER JOIN LINK_LA_TYP ON LAT_TYP_ID = 243 AND 
    LAT_GA_ID = LGS_GA_ID 
    INNER JOIN LINK_ART ON LA_ID = LAT_LA_ID 
    INNER JOIN ARTICLES ON ART_ID = LA_ART_ID 
    INNER JOIN DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID AND 
    DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = 35 
    INNER JOIN DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID 
    INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS ON SUP_ID = ART_SUP_ID 
WHERE LGS_STR_ID = 42189;
```

Q2 results: Returned 833 rows, 0.749 seconds.

Q4 results: Return 836 rows, 3.72 seconds.

As you see, there is huge difference. Same queries with different parameters on the Q4 database can take upto 15 seconds.

I've tried tweaking some setttings in my.cnf, but nothing seems to help.

EXPLAINS:

[Quarter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN6Wu.jpg)

[Quarter 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzVzO.jpg)

Comment: Maybe irrelevant but easy to provide: Can you please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34656537/edit) the result of [`EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT ART_ID.....`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to your question? If the results differ, please for both servers.

Comment: I provided EXPLAIN queries in images.

Comment: Wild guessing mode: If you (for debugging purposes only) remove the DISTINCT: a) Does the `using temporary` disappear from the EXPLAIN result? b) Do the execution times for both servers draw nearer?

Comment: a) `using temporary` disappears from EXPLAIN result
b) Without `DISTINCT` query runs: Q2: 2.0 seconds, Q4: 3.8 seconds

Comment: Still in wild guessing mode. I hope you don't mind (tell me if you do; more than that I cannot offer and the outcome is ...questionable). Eliminating the temporary table the ratio changed in favour of Q4. Given the relative small number of estimated rows to be examined and the apparent use of simple indices I'd say the overall performance is ...not overwhelming. What hardware do you use? Is there a difference in hardware used by Q2/Q4? Even if virtualized do they hit the same storage device, have the same amoutn of RAM, ...?

Comment: Is hardware identical for both dbs? Also, you can run *show variables;* to check for config differences. If its an MyISAM table you can run *optimize table...*

Comment: Those databases are located in same server, using google cloud computing: n1-standard   (vCPUs: 1, RAM: 3.75 GB)

Comment: Using 150GB persistent disk, i just checked the storage and saw there are only 1.2GB available, can this affect performance?

Comment: Possibly. But that is something I'd ask the good admin folks over at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) ;-)

Comment: On second thought, those databases are located in the same disk so this would affect both of them.

Comment: I've cloned that VM and gave it a bigger 170GB disk, made no difference performance-wise.